# Include command line to Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, dotnet-isolated

How can I add a command line argument for when my app starts?

I'm using the Azure Functions in an isolated process, and after publish command, the `worker.config.json` file is created. I didn't find much documentation about this file, but I have tried to edit it and add the "arguments" property, then it seems something like this:

```
{
  "description": {
    "language": "dotnet-isolated",
    "extensions": [ ".dll" ],
    "defaultExecutablePath": "dotnet",
    "defaultWorkerPath": "MyFunctionProjectName.dll",
    "workerIndexing": "false",
    "arguments": ["foo-bar"]
  }
}
```

But when my function starts, the below error is thrown.

```
[Information] The application 'foo-bar' does not exist.
```

So, how can I add command line arguments to my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have reproduced by creating HttpTrigger Azure function in visual studio.
- To create a C# function in Azure from the command line, you can refer the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=azure-powershell,isolated-process).
- After creating the Azure function, I have tried to add the property "arguments" in worker.config.json file and run the project as below:

```json
{

"description": {

"language": "dotnet-isolated",

"extensions": [ ".dll" ],

"defaultExecutablePath": "dotnet",

"defaultWorkerPath": "FunctionApp7.dll",

"workerIndexing": "false",

"arguments": ["foo-bar"]

}

}
```

**Result:**
[image]

- can be seen the same in portal:

[image]

[image]